# WebView still loads url even if shouldOverrideUrlLoading returns false

Tags: android, android-webview

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);  // Also tried with return false;
}
```

`onPageStarted` and `onPageFinished` are empty.

Still `WebView` loads the Url.

Answer (score 1):

I think If you don't want to load url then you have to return **true** in **shouldOverrideUrlLoading** method.

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) 
{
   return true;
}
```

Please check this once, it may work.